# ~/anaconda/bin/conda: No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

I have `matplotlib` version `1.5.3` and I want to update it to the latest version. I used the command `conda update matplotlib`. I got the following:

```
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment ~/anaconda:

The following packages will be downloaded:

package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
jpeg-9c                    |       h470a237_0         246 KB  conda-forge
libpng-1.6.34              |       ha92aebf_1         321 KB  conda-forge
olefile-0.45.1             |             py_1          30 KB  conda-forge
pycosat-0.6.3              |   py27h470a237_1         111 KB  conda-forge
requests-2.13.0            |           py27_0         771 KB  conda-forge
subprocess32-3.5.2         |           py27_0          38 KB  conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache-1.5|             py_1           6 KB  conda-forge
pyopenssl-16.2.0           |           py27_0          70 KB  conda-forge
conda-4.5.8                |           py27_1         633 KB  conda-forge
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:         2.2 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

backports.functools_lru_cache: 1.5-py_1          conda-forge
kiwisolver:                    1.0.1-py27_1      conda-forge
olefile:                       0.45.1-py_1       conda-forge
subprocess32:                  3.5.2-py27_0      conda-forge

The following packages will be UPDATED:

anaconda:                      4.2.0-np111py27_0             --> custom-py27_0                   
conda:                         4.2.13-py27_0     conda-forge --> 4.5.8-py27_1         conda-forge
freetype:                      2.5.5-1                       --> 2.8.1-0              conda-forge
jpeg:                          8d-2                          --> 9c-h470a237_0        conda-forge
libpng:                        1.6.22-0                      --> 1.6.34-ha92aebf_1    conda-forge
libtiff:                       4.0.6-2                       --> 4.0.9-0              conda-forge
matplotlib:                    1.5.3-np111py27_0             --> 2.2.2-py27_1         conda-forge
pillow:                        3.3.1-py27_0                  --> 5.0.0-py27_0         conda-forge
pycosat:                       0.6.1-py27_1                  --> 0.6.3-py27h470a237_1 conda-forge
pyopenssl:                     16.0.0-py27_0                 --> 16.2.0-py27_0        conda-forge
requests:                      2.11.1-py27_0                 --> 2.13.0-py27_0        conda-forge
zlib:                          1.2.8-3                       --> 1.2.11-h470a237_3    conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Fetching packages ...
jpeg-9c-h470a2 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 450.22 kB/s
libpng-1.6.34- 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 555.99 kB/s
olefile-0.45.1 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 257.16 kB/s
pycosat-0.6.3- 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 328.60 kB/s
requests-2.13. 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 796.35 kB/s
subprocess32-3 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 121.53 kB/s
backports.func 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00   1.88 MB/s
pyopenssl-16.2 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 220.40 kB/s
conda-4.5.8-py 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00 793.41 kB/s
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|####################################################################################################| 100%
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|####################################################################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
Installing conda-forge::olefile-0.45.1-py_1 requires a minimum conda version of 4.3.
```

It seems that `conda` got uninstalled and the new version cannot be installed. When I try `conda list` or `source activate clean` I get the error:

```
-bash: ~/anaconda/bin/conda: No such file or directory
```

Also `conda update conda` doesn't work.

I really need to fix this quickly as `conda` seems broken. I am using a mac if this helps.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that conda was unlinked and the error occurred before the replacement could be linked back in. I would suggest completely uninstalling then reinstalling. Also, if you're using the `anaconda` meta-package, it is better to `conda update anaconda` rather than updating any of the individual packages.

Comment: I am using `anaconda` but I cannot use `conda update anaconda` since `conda` is not available.

Comment: Right, I meant in the future after you reinstall Anaconda from scratch, update `anaconda` rather than individual packages. If you need a particular version of some dependency for a project, make a new environment.